# The smtp service is not working but there is no errors .net6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to implement a mail service to use it with sending reset password email, I tried to use Gmail and it doesn't work so I switched to outlook but it still not working. Can anybody help? Thanks

```
private SmtpClient _client;
       public StringBuilder _body;

       public EmailService()
       {
           _body = new StringBuilder();
           _client = new SmtpClient();
       }
       public void Dispose()
       {
           _body.Clear();
           _client.Dispose();
       }
       public async Task<bool> SendEmailAsync(string fullname, string receiverEmail, string subject)
       {
           try
           {
               MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
               mail.To.Add(receiverEmail);
               mail.From = new MailAddress("testmoenergy@outlook.com", "Aljawhara", Encoding.UTF8);
               mail.Subject = subject;
               mail.Body = _body.ToString();
               mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
               mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
               _client.Host = "smtp.outlook.com";
               _client.Port = 587;
               _client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
               _client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testmoenergy@outlook.com", "test******");
               _client.EnableSsl = true;
               await _client.SendMailAsync(mail);
               return true;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               throw new Exception(ex.Message);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest that you don't use these user email providers to send emails from your system.
Match better to take reliable providers such as Mailgun, Send Grid and so on.

Comment: _" I tried to use Gmail and it doesn't work so I switched to outlook but it still not working."_ You will have to give us more details about "not working".

Answer (score 0):

**The Gmail oauth is not allowing users to send mail from 1-may 2022**. you have to create a auth key from you gmail account and use it as password.

```
string username = "yourmailID";
string password = "yourauthcode";
ICredentialsByHost credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient()
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    Credentials = credentials
};

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(username);
mail.To.Add(username);
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.Body = body;

smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

for generate auth code

In gmail go to you account settings--> security-->enable two step verfication to ON  -->app passwords--> give you custom app name and click generate .

This will give your auth code.

[image]

[image]